# Modular Tkinter Window Opens Two Window When Run

Tags: python, class, tkinter, module

When I run my Tkinter code the results end up giving me two Tkinter windows. One has the widgets/items my code says but one is a completely blank window.

file 1-

```
from tkinter import*


class Screen:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.Tk = Tk()
        self.items = items
        self.Tk.mainloop()
```

file 2-

```
from tkinter import*
from Screen import*





class Module1:
    def __init__(self):
        Test_button = Button(text="Test")
        Test_button.pack()
        
items = Module1()

Mainscreen = Screen(items)
```

I just want to make a modular Tkinter screen so my code is not that messy

-Just want one/common Tkinter window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the trouble is you're going about things backwards a bit. You'll want to import your modules into the Python file containting your "root" window class (aka `Screen`), rather than the other way around.

The typical way to handle a "root" window class in tkinter usually looks like this, where the class inherits directly from `Tk()`

```
# this is the first file...
import tkinter as tk  # avoid star imports!
from file2 import Module1  # import your widget classes here
# note that depending on your project structure you may need to do
# 'from .file2 import Module1' instead (this is called a 'relative import')


class Screen(tk.Tk):  # the 'Screen' class inherits from 'tk.Tk'
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # initialize tkinter.Tk()
        # instance your module widgets by calling the class like so
        # (you'll need to update Module1 as shown below here)
        self.mod1 = Module1(self)  # 'self' refers to 'Screen', the main window
```

You'll need to update the `Module1` class so it can be bound to your parent `Screen`

```
# this is the second file...
import tkinter as tk  # again, star imports bad...


class Module1:
    def __init__(self, parent):  # add the parent parameter
        # whenever you instance your 'Module1' class, it will expect a 'parent';
        # above, we used self (i.e. 'Screen') - this is where your 'button' is going!
        self.parent = parent
        test_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Test")
        test_button.pack()
```

And you'll run the `mainloop()` method on an *instance* of your `Screen` class at the end of your main Python file like so

```
# this is the first file again...
if __name__ == '__main__':  # if this script is being run at the top level...
    app = Screen()  # get an instance of your Screen class
    app.mainloop()  # run the GUI loop
```